# Get currently playing song title and artist

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I get the currently playing song title and artist in Windows Phone 7? I know I have to do it with the [MediaHistory.NowPlaying Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistory.nowplaying%28VS.92%29.aspx) but I couldn't figure out how to use this. I tried

```
string title = MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying.Title;
```

but it gives me a NullReferenceException even when a song is playing.

Comment: This isn't an answer, so much as an explanation: the MediaHistory class only applies to media that your application is playing; it won't return results for songs played by another applications (like the built-in Music+Videos application.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
```

and

```
string name = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Name;
string album = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Album.Name;
```

You can get much more information about the playing song like this...

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistory.nowplaying%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and take a look at this, it explains why you get error

> When getting this property, only the most recent MediaHistoryItem set
>   by your application is returned. For example, if the user has played a
>   more recent MediaHistoryItem through a different application, that
>   item will not be returned with this property. Instead, the most recent
>   item set by your own application is returned.