# WP7 how to get current song

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a track which is playing on my phone and then I pause it using the controls that pop down after pressing the volume keys.

In my application, how can I resume that song and find out what the song is?

The following does not work.

```
MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong   // This reports no songs at all. Only works if I give it a song to play
MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying.Title  // MediaHistory.Instance = null
```

Also just trying this does nothing.

```
MediaPlayer.Resume
```

Edit: If it makes any difference, I am debugging a Windows Phone 7 app on and Windows Phone 8 device.

If I give a song to MediaPlayer to play then all the above works.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439150/get-currently-playing-song-title-and-artist

Comment: @dowhilefor Gaz83 is essentially saying that the answer to that question isn't working.

Comment: @jerry Correct, I have searched on here before posting :-)

Comment: For future reference, linking the other question (whether you got the code from there or not) may help avoid misunderstandings like that.

Answer (score 1):

to play a song

```
MediaPlayer.Play(SongCollection songs);

 MediaPlayer.Play(SongCollection songs,int index);
```

and to get songs

```
 MediaLibrary mLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
            songs = mLibrary.Songs;
```

to check current state

```
if(MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing || MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Paused)
```

and to check active song

```
 Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Name;
```